# Is it possible to store copies of outbound messages in a user's sent items folder even if they didn't personally send them?

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010

Exchange 2010

I have a third-party server that sends some emails on behalf of various users. Is it possible for these messages to go through my Exchange 2010 server on the way out and have it copy the message to the respective user's sent item's folder?

Comment: Only if exchange sees a copy can it store it.  Maybe you could CC the user and have a rule that moves it to the sent items.

Comment: Thanks @uSlackr  When you mentioned having a rule, do you mean on the client Outlook? I'm interested in a server-side change.

Comment: yes.  Keep in mind some Outlook rules are server-side. Unless you have to do a pattern match, the server should still handle most rules.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following links, I'm not too familiar with exchange myself but the Messaging policy sounds like what you are after.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998599

http://allcomputers.us/windows_server/exchange-server-2010---managing-records-%28part-2%29---administrating-managed-folders.aspx